# Preprocessor syntax to use an #define as an identifier (function name) and a string

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I would like to create a shared object file and I would like to make it easy to use by having a `#define` that can be used to dereference the function names.

In **libfoo.h**

```
#define FOO_SO_FUNCTION_A    aFunction
```

In **libfoo.so**

```
#include "libfoo/libfoo.h"

extern "C" int FOO_SO_FUNCTION_A( void )
{
    ...
}
```

In **clientfoo**

```
#include "libfoo/libfoo.h"

...
libfoofunc = dlsym( libfoo, MAKE_STRING(FOO_SO_FUNCTION_A) );
```

My problem is that

```
#FOO_SO_FUNCTION_A
```

Will simply change into "FOO_SO_FUNCTION_A" because the preprocessor rightfully  only runs once.  Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
#define REALLY_MAKE_STRING(x) #x
#define MAKE_STRING(x) REALLY_MAKE_STRING(x)
```

Due to some details of the rules when exactly the preprocessors substitutes macros, an extra level of indirection is required.

Comment: Note to others looking at this.  Don't forget to #include the file that defines the identifier you want to replace with, otherwise you're going to scratch your head wondering why the expansion isn't working and you keep getting the static text.